# Ubuntu 13.04 freezes on login

Tags: partitioning, login, screen

I have a serious problem with my copy of Ubuntu. I had Debian 7.1, and had no idea about how to install Ubuntu. I tried with tutorials off of other sites, but every time I log in Ubuntu, it completely freezes, and my screen shows some sort of lines made up diagonally, leaving it unusable.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 in the exact same partition as Debian 7.1 (erasing it) with 168GB. I made the entire install correctly, no problems. But I had this problem even when I was **trying** Ubuntu, when I booted the DVD for the 2nd time, it started correctly, but I still had the exact thing in some places, eg.: Applications list.

Tutorial: [How to Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail#.UqH5GEPI9ol)
Tutorial (mirror): [How to Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://web.archive.org/web/20130929210002/http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail)

**`Specifications`**

```
Motherboard:           AMD M2N68-AM SE2
Processor:             AMD Sempron LE-1250 2.2Ghz   
RAM:                   2GB DDR2 RAM
HDD:                   320GB HDD
Integrated video card: nVidia GeForce 7025/nForce 630a
Monitor:               Samsung SyncMaster S19B300
Connection:            Wired
```

Comment: Please read [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](http://askubuntu.com/a/14126/159545), [edit] your question to include more hardware information. Also, include the tutorials you've followed and what have you done.

Comment: Added everything you said.

Comment: Did you have any problems with Debian 7? Please add screenshots of the problem. (You can upload the pictures to a image hosting site like ImgUrl or ImageShack.)

Comment: I had no problems with Debian 7, none at all, i'll try to take a picture of my problem and upload them.

Comment: No GRUB (it only showed ONCE yesterday) : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/ktg5.jpg/ (sorry for the blurred image)


Normal boot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/lwxh.jpg/


Normal login: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/efp9.jpg/


It freezes right here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/u4i9.jpg/ (it stops at that point and stops spining)


And finally, the big problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/ymsz.jpg/

Comment: Most possible the image you used to install Ubuntu is corrupt, try downloading it via BitTorrent. (If Debian 7 works, then Ubuntu Raring should probably work without a hitch, I think.)

Comment: Ok, i'll try with BitTorrent tomorrow, because i'm in bed xD And I guess that I can use .exe apps in Ubuntu with wine, can I? For example, games, photoshop, etc.

Comment: Ok, i'll install it, i'll be updating this comment while i'm installing ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know why i can't edit my comment, it doesn't matter. At the beginning, I tried Ubuntu from the DVD I used to burn the BitTorrent image. None of the apps in the apps list appeared just like normal. They were similar to the last photo I uploaded. Ubuntu is installing, so i'll wait

Answer (score 3):

[Edwin's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329063/ubuntu-13-04-freezes-on-login#comment418654_329063) appeared to [solve this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329063/ubuntu-13-04-freezes-on-login#comment419556_329063):

> Most possible the image you used to install Ubuntu is corrupt, try
>   downloading it via BitTorrent. (If Debian 7 works, then Ubuntu Raring
>   should probably work without a hitch, I think.)